# Search a particular class in css with php

Tags: php, css, search

I'm using flaticon for a web project. I have to show in a div all the icons that are present in the file flaticonicon.css.

So I have to extrapolate *flaticonicon-add121* , *flaticonicon-alarm57* , *flaticonicon-appointment* ect etc

To do this I have written the following code

```
    $handle = @fopen("flaticonicon.css", "r");
    $a = 0;
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

            if (strpos($buffer,':before') !== false) {
                $a++;
                if($a > 1 && $buffer[0] != "}"){

                    $c = preg_split("/:/", $buffer , NULL);
                    $c = $c[0];
                    $c = substr($c, 1 , strlen($c));

                    echo "<span class='".$c."'></span>";
                    echo "\r\n";

                }

            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

That works perfectly on this type of css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FlaticonIcon";
    src: url("flaticonicon.eot");
    src: url("flaticonicon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("flaticonicon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("flaticonicon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("flaticonicon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticonicon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticonicon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticonicon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticonicon-"]:after {   
    font-family: FlaticonIcon;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.flaticonicon-add121:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
.flaticonicon-alarm57:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
.flaticonicon-appointment:before {
    content: "\e002";
}
.flaticonicon-armchair1:before {
    content: "\e003";
}
.flaticonicon-audio49:before {
    content: "\e004";
}
.flaticonicon-baseball24:before {
    content: "\e005";
}
.flaticon-etc etc
```

The problem is that the css file will not remain so, at the end of the project will minify in something like this , and in this way my code does not correctly read all the classes of the icons.

```
@font-face{font-family:"FlaticonIcon";src:url("flaticonicon.eot");src:url("flaticonicon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("flaticonicon.woff") format("woff"),url("flaticonicon.ttf") format("truetype"),url("flaticonicon.svg") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}[class^="flaticonicon-"]:before,[class*=" flaticonicon-"]:before,[class^="flaticonicon-"]:after,[class*=" flaticonicon-"]:after{font-family:FlaticonIcon;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;margin-left:20px}.flaticonicon-add121:before{content:"\e000"}.flaticonicon-alarm57:before{content:"\e001"}.flaticonicon-appointment:before{content:"\e002"}.flaticonicon-armchair1:before{content:"\e003"}.flaticonicon-audio49:before{content:"\e004"}.flaticonicon-baseball24:before{content:"\e005"}.flaticonicon-basin:before{content:"\e006"}.flaticonicon-basketball32:before{content:"\e007"}.flaticonicon-bath2:before{content:"\e008"}.flaticonicon-bathroom1:before{content:"\e009"}.flaticonicon- ........ }
```

I've seen similar questions to this, and I think the right solution is to use a regular expression

---

### update..

Even just to be able to extrapolate the text between {....}, it would be very useful, at that point it would be simple

### update..

This can help

```
$c = file_get_contents('flaticonicon.css');
$cc = split('[{}]', $c);
```

### update..

This is my solution

```
$c = file_get_contents('flaticonicon.css');
$cc = split('[{}]', $c);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($cc) ; $i++){
    if(substr($cc[$i], 0 , 14) == ".flaticonicon-"){
        $app = preg_split("/:/", $cc[$i] , null);
        $app = substr($app[0], 1,strlen($app[0]));
        echo $app."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a star in regex, but it seems like this does the trick:

```
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match_all('/\.flaticon[^:]*/', $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches[0],true).'</pre>';
```

You only need to remove the leading dot to get the names. Result on your compressed css:

> ```
> [0] => .flaticonicon-add121
> [1] => .flaticonicon-alarm57
> [2] => .flaticonicon-appointment
> [3] => .flaticonicon-armchair1
> [4] => .flaticonicon-audio49
> [5] => .flaticonicon-baseball24
> [6] => .flaticonicon-basin
> [7] => .flaticonicon-basketball32
> [8] => .flaticonicon-bath2
> [9] => .flaticonicon-bathroom1
> ```

Comment: you can improve the regex a little bit -> `/\.(flaticonicon-[^:]*)/i` or `/\.flaticonicon-([^:]*)/i` where you'll get the whole match in index 0 in your array and just the class in index 1 (`$matches[0] or $matches[1]`)